# What's in my windshield and how can I remove it?

Tags: windshield

The glass in my windshield has these stains that can only be seen at night, either when there's light shining and/or it's raining.

I bought three products at pepboys that are supposed to clean glass/windshields, but they didn't work for this type of stain.

The weird thing is that you can't feel it in the glass, it's almost as if it is part of the glass.

Does anyone know what it is and how I can remove it? I'm including a picture.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does this appear to be like rain streaks or from water running down the windshield? I have seen similar things on my cars. Water stains or road salt from winter driving. It does take a long long time to clean up, if ever. IMO some stains, like salt, almost never go away once they etch into the glass.

Comment: One thing to try would be to shine a light at an very low angle across the glass in a dark place and see if you see the same pattern. The objective is to see if the low angle light shows any surface etching. Hold the light and shine the beam almost parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Are the marks 'in' the glass?

The glass will be laminated, so if the marks are in the plastic inner lamination, then you won't be able to remove them.  It could be that the laminations have separated slightly.

Comment: And if it is in the plastic inner - the only solution is : fit a new screen....

Comment: The OP is stating they can feel whatever it is on the glass, so I don't think it's delaminating.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The OP said - The weird thing is that you can't feel it in the glass.

Comment: Sorry, completely misread it. I guess my earlier suggestion of glass polishing won't work either. Thanks for cluing me! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No problem.